# Problems with JTextfield and JButton

Tags: button, listener, frame

I wrote some code for a login screen with a JTextfield and a JButton- the text field is not showing up, I think what's happening is that the button is taking up the entire frame. Help greatly appreciated! Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Dimension;
public class LoginPanel extends JPanel
{
 private JButton login;
 public JTextField field;
 public LoginPanel()
   {
       JFrame frame = new JFrame();
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.setTitle("Log In");
       frame.setLocation(500,400);
       frame.setSize(500,500);
       frame.pack();
       frame.setVisible(true);
       JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter your ID number:");
       JTextArea  textarea = new JTextArea(5,30);
       JTextField textfield = new JTextField(20);
       JButton login= new JButton("Log In");
      login.setSize(200,200);
       frame.add(label);
       frame.add(textarea);
       frame.add(login);
       setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,40));
       login.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());      
       JTextField field= new JTextField(10);
}
public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
  String ID= field.getText();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I belive this will work

```
public class LoginPanel extends JPanel
{
private JFrame frame;
private JTextArea textarea;
    public LoginPanel()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        textarea = new JTextArea(5,30);
        frame.add(this);
        this.add(textarea);
        // don't add it to the frame, add the textfield to the panel 
    }
}
```